# Empty cell not sets to DateTime type

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Trying to set google spreadsheet column to `DateTime` format. Unfortunately it remains `Automatic`.

[image]

This causes `String` type return instead of `DateTime` while call [Google Sheets API spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

```
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, "LV!A2:D");
ValueRange response = request.Execute();
IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var row in values)
    {
        log.InfoFormat("{0} {1} {2} {3}", row[0].GetType(), row[1].GetType(), row[2].GetType(), row[3].GetType());
        value.Add(new Fb((string) row[0], (DateTime) row[1], (DateTime) row[2], (string) row[3]));
    }
}
```

How to set column always remain `DateTime` ?

Comment: Have you tried setting dateTimeRenderOption?

Comment: How to use dateTimeRenderOption ?

Comment: Check the documentation its one of the optional vars [values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)  just add it to your request before you fire execute.